# Is there a way to reset all l3keys keys to their initial value?

Tags: expl3, latex3, key-value, l3keys

This is a general and documented feature of latex3, but I shall still provide an MWE in order to illustrate the problem, see below.

Suppose I have a function which uses the l3keys key-value interface, and I want it to have reasonable defaults for when the user does not provide the key. l3keys provides the `default` and `initial` options, where `default` is used when the key is given without a value and `initial` is used to initialise the key. However, this initialisation happens exactly once, at the time the key is defined.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mykeys } {
  myvalue .int_set:N = \l_myvalue_int,
  myvalue .initial:n = 0
}
\cs_new:Nn \show_zero_or_myvalue:n {
  \keys_set:nn { mykeys } { #1 }
  \int_use:N \l_myvalue_int
}

show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
show_zero_or_myvalue:n { myvalue=5 }
show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

As a user, with the function definition hidden in some package, I would expect this to result in the output `050`. Of course, once you read the l3keys documentation, you know that it actually prints `055`, because the key `myvalue` is not set in the third call, so it retains its previous value.

However, there are situations where this is undesirable. Imagine you were drawing a picture with TikZ and the code

```
\tikz[color=black]{
% define some nodes
\draw[color=red] (a) -- (b);
\draw (b) -- (c);
}
```

resulted in two red lines.

Obviously, I can reset the key in the backend by hand, but since I am working with a large collection of keys that are read in multiple places, my current workaround is that before *every* call to `\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { #1 }`, I issue a manual `\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { ... }`, where `...` is a long, long list of keys.

Is there a better way to do this, either built into l3keys or by hooking into the `set_keys` mechanism?

There have been questions on this topic a while ago, but none with a definitive answer. Since latex3 is still being developed, I think asking again is reasonable.

Related: if there is no built-in way, what is the standard mechanism to propose the inclusion of this feature? Evidently I am not the only person who would like to see something like this.

Comment: It sounds like you want to group the settings: that's nothing to do with keys _per se_ though

Comment: TikZ/PGFkeys works the same: `\path` begins and `;` ends a group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two strategies for this.

One is what's employed also by Ti*k*Z, namely grouping.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mykeys } {
  myvalue .int_set:N = \l_myvalue_int,
  myvalue .initial:n = 0
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \show_zero_or_myvalue:n {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { mykeys } { #1 }
  \int_use:N \l_myvalue_int
  \group_end:
}

\show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
\show_zero_or_myvalue:n { myvalue=5 }
\show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Since the setting of the keys is done locally, the initial value will be restored upon group ending.

Second strategy: keep a list of the keys that should be reset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mykeys } {
  myvalue .int_set:N = \l_myvalue_int,
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \show_zero_or_myvalue:n {
  \keys_set:nn { mykeys } { myvalue=0,#1 }
  \int_use:N \l_myvalue_int
}

\show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
\show_zero_or_myvalue:n { myvalue=5 }
\show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

If you have several keys to reset, you can define a shorthand

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \betta_reset: {
  \keys_set:nn { mykeys } { myvalue=0 }
}
```

and add `\betta_reset:` before `\keys_set:nn` in the function `\show_zero_or_myvalue:n`.

Comment: Fair enough, I forgot about grouping. I was explicitly looking for a way to avoid adding a `\betta_reset` style function, so grouping does what I want.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative in `expl3` to the [possibilities shown by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664481/117050) is to precompile standard-settings into a token list. This is (in principal) the same idea as

> Second strategy: keep a list of the keys that should be reset.

but is faster.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_bettageorge_defaults_tl
\keys_define:nn { mykeys } {
  myvalue .int_set:N = \l_myvalue_int,
  myvalue .initial:n = 0
}
\keys_precompile:nnN { mykeys } { myvalue=0 } \l_bettageorge_defaults_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \show_zero_or_myvalue:n {
  \l_bettageorge_defaults_tl
  \keys_set:nn { mykeys } { #1 }
  \int_use:N \l_myvalue_int
}

\show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
\show_zero_or_myvalue:n { myvalue=5 }
\show_zero_or_myvalue:n {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```