# Why can I not correctly reset a key in l3keys?

Tags: latex3, key-value, l3keys

To help me learn `l3keys` I created two small demos.

The first uses `l3keys` for a command and seems to work correctly as far as I can tell.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { foo }{ Command }
\msg_new:nnnn { foo }{ unknownoption }
  { Unknown~option. }{ Try~again~but~with~a~known~option. }

\tl_new:N \l__foo_thing_tl
\tl_new:N \l__foo_towhom_tl
\keys_define:nn { foo }
  {
    thing   .tl_set:N = \l__foo_thing_tl ,
    thing   .default:n = door ,
    thing   .initial:n = ice  ,
    towhom  .tl_set:N = \l__foo_towhom_tl ,
    towhom  .default:n = Dana ,
    towhom  .initial:n = Ina  ,
    unknown .code:n = \msg_fatal:nn { foo }{ unknownoption }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__foo_foo:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { foo } { #1 }
      #2~\l__foo_thing_tl \c_space_tl to~\l__foo_towhom_tl.
    \group_end:
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foosetup } { m }
  { \keys_set:nn { foo } { #1 } }

\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foo } { O{} m }
  {
    \__foo_foo:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
This demo shows how to use \texttt{l3keys} for a command.

\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foo[thing]{Give the}                \par
\foo[thing,towhom]{Give the}         \par
\foo[thing=car,towhom=Tom]{Give the} \par
\foosetup{thing=apple}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foo[towhom]{Give the}               \par
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output from first MWE]

The second uses `l3keys` for a package and seems to work correctly except in one case where a key doesn't correctly initialize.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{foopkg.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{foopkg}{}{}{}
\msg_new:nnnn { foopkg }{ unknownoption }
  { Unknown~option. }{ Try~again~but~with~a~known~option. }

\tl_new:N \l__foopkg_thing_tl
\tl_new:N \l__foopkg_towhom_tl
\keys_define:nn { foopkg }
  {
    thing   .tl_set:N  = \l__foopkg_thing_tl ,
    thing   .default:n = door ,
    thing   .initial:n = ice  ,
    towhom  .tl_set:N  = \l__foopkg_towhom_tl ,
    towhom  .default:n = Dana ,
    towhom  .initial:n = Ina  ,
    unknown .code:n    = \msg_fatal:nn { foopkg }{ unknownoption }
  }

\ProcessKeyOptions[foopkg]

\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foosetup } { m }
  { \keys_set:nn { foopkg } { #1 } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__foopkg_foo:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { foopkg } { #1 }
    #2~\l__foopkg_thing_tl \c_space_tl to~\l__foopkg_towhom_tl.
    \group_end:
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foo } { O{} m }
  {
    \__foopkg_foo:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[thing=vase,towhom=Val]{foopkg}
\usepackage{foopkg}

\begin{document}
This demo shows how to use \texttt{l3keys} for a package.

\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=door}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing,towhom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=car,towhom=Tom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=apple}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{towhom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output from the second MWE]

In the second demo, the second occurrence of `Tom` should ideally be `Ina` but I don't understand why the key doesn't reset. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664479/218142) seems relevant but I'm already, I think, using the solution there and either I'm doing something wrong or I'm not understanding something simple. Can the two demos be made to give the same results?

Comment: it has nothing to do with package or not. You use more \footsetup in your second example and that is not grouped.

Comment: I could not figure out how to use grouping in the `\foosetup` command.

Comment: well typically you don't want grouping, I mean it is a setup command so naturally it should affect following calls to the key.

Comment: Sure that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `initial:n` property is what the variable is set to when `\keys_define:nn` is executed, *i.e.* equivalent to applying `\keys_set:nn`. Thus is applies exactly once. If you want reset keys before the start of `\keys_set:nn` in a case where the keys are not set in a group, add the key to the start of the list:

```latex
\keys_set:nn { foopkg } { towhom = Ina , #1 }
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that (from the linked question) but obviously didn't do it correctly. Seems to work properly now.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is adequately described in [Joseph's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711798/117050): `.initial:n` just sets the key once.

Instead of adding the keys to the list and introducing parsing overhead every time you could also just parse the key=value pair once and compile the result into a token list you use to reset the key:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{foopkg.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{foopkg}{}{}{}
\msg_new:nnnn { foopkg }{ unknownoption }
  { Unknown~option. }{ Try~again~but~with~a~known~option. }

\tl_new:N \l__foopkg_thing_tl
\tl_new:N \l__foopkg_towhom_tl
\tl_new:N \l__foopkg_reset_defaults_tl
\keys_define:nn { foopkg }
  {
    thing   .tl_set:N  = \l__foopkg_thing_tl ,
    thing   .default:n = door ,
    thing   .initial:n = ice  ,
    towhom  .tl_set:N  = \l__foopkg_towhom_tl ,
    towhom  .default:n = Dana ,
    towhom  .initial:n = Ina  ,
    unknown .code:n    = \msg_fatal:nn { foopkg }{ unknownoption }
  }

\ProcessKeyOptions[foopkg]

\keys_precompile:nnN { foopkg } { towhom = Ina } \l__foopkg_reset_defaults_tl
\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foosetup } { m }
  {
    \l__foopkg_reset_defaults_tl
    \keys_set:nn { foopkg } { #1 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__foopkg_foo:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { foopkg } { #1 }
    #2~\l__foopkg_thing_tl \c_space_tl to~\l__foopkg_towhom_tl.
    \group_end:
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foo } { O{} m }
  {
    \__foopkg_foo:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[thing=vase,towhom=Val]{foopkg}
\usepackage{foopkg}

\begin{document}
This demo shows how to use \texttt{l3keys} for a package.

\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=door}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing,towhom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=car,towhom=Tom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=apple}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{towhom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\end{document}
```

---

A small variation, which I think is more correct than using a `tl` to reset the values:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{foopkg.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{foopkg}{}{}{}
\msg_new:nnnn { foopkg }{ unknownoption }
  { Unknown~option. }{ Try~again~but~with~a~known~option. }

\tl_new:N \l__foopkg_thing_tl
\tl_new:N \l__foopkg_towhom_tl
\keys_define:nn { foopkg }
  {
    thing   .tl_set:N  = \l__foopkg_thing_tl ,
    thing   .default:n = door ,
    thing   .initial:n = ice  ,
    towhom  .tl_set:N  = \l__foopkg_towhom_tl ,
    towhom  .default:n = Dana ,
    towhom  .initial:n = Ina  ,
    unknown .code:n    = \msg_fatal:nn { foopkg }{ unknownoption }
  }

\ProcessKeyOptions[foopkg]

\group_begin:
  \keys_precompile:nnN { foopkg } { towhom = Ina } \l_tmpa_tl
  \exp_args:NNV \cs_new_protected:Npn \__foopkg_reset_defaults: \l_tmpa_tl
\group_end:
\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foosetup } { m }
  {
    \__foopkg_reset_defaults:
    \keys_set:nn { foopkg } { #1 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__foopkg_foo:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { foopkg } { #1 }
    #2~\l__foopkg_thing_tl \c_space_tl to~\l__foopkg_towhom_tl.
    \group_end:
  }

\DeclareDocumentCommand{ \foo } { O{} m }
  {
    \__foopkg_foo:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[thing=vase,towhom=Val]{foopkg}
\usepackage{foopkg}

\begin{document}
This demo shows how to use \texttt{l3keys} for a package.

\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=door}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing,towhom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=car,towhom=Tom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{thing=apple}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\foosetup{towhom}
\foo{Give the}                       \par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh I like that approach very much.

Comment: I'm curious about why you didn't use `\tl_use:N \l__foopkg_reset_defaults_tl` before `\keys_set:nn`. It doesn't look as though it matters, but I'm curious.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL for a `tl` it is documented behaviour that the `\tl_use:N` is optional and you can also use it directly. If you prefer it you can put it there.

Comment: I see I misread the relevant sentence in `interface3.pdf`. Thank you.

Comment: I'd really prefer a different approach really, I'll update my answer with that alternative...